# attempting to delete an object in many to one relation but will not delete django. Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

I am deleting a model in a many to one relation. Youll notice in the delete method I am exposing the parent model. This is for permissions which I will write later.

The code is not deleting the objects.

As in method runs and my javascript removes the object. But If I reload the page, I get the objects back.

what could be happening?

```
 def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        venuepk = kwargs.get('venuepk', None)
        venue = get_object_or_404(Venue, pk=venuepk)
        venuerooms = venue.room_set.all()
        roompk = kwargs.get('roompk')
        roomobject = None
        for room in venuerooms:
            if room.pk == roompk:
               roomobject = Room.objects.get(pk=roompk)
               roomobject.delete()
               return Response({})

        return Response(status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: did you cross-checked with your DB ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I got it. needed to cast the roompk to an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem

```
if room.pk == roompk:
```

Is the pk of the room a string, or is it an integer??  Probably an integer.  Whereas the value of venuepk which you get from kwargs is most likely a string.  Therefore the comparison will fail.

A better way to do this is:

```
venueroom = VenueRoom.objects.filter(roompk).first()
if venueroom is not None:
    # you can get venue from room.. assuming the name of the ForeignKey 
    # field connecting room to its venue is called `venue`.
    venue = venueroom.venue
    venueroom.delete()
    # return success
else:
    # return failure
```

This avoids the problem of having to bring all the related objects into memory in order to find the right one.  It asks the database for just the one object you need.  The lookup works because when doing filter, a comparison between an integer column and a string representation of an integer is ok.. at least in postgres it works...

or

```
if venue.room_set.filter(pk=venuepk).delete():
    # return success
else:
    # return failure
```

This doesn't bring the object into memory at all, it just tells the database to find the matching object and delete it.  But then, if you've overridden the delete method on the model, that won't be called.  I don't think signals will be called either.  But if that doesn't matter in your application, then this is the most efficient.

Comment: thank you. I casted the roompk to an int. You can see my answer below. I like both of your answers. I am doing it in the way I am now so I can have access to the parent object venue. For permissions reasons. Thank you for taking the time

Comment: If you do it using my first suggestion, then you can get the venue object from the room object.. eg `venue = venueroom.venue`.. assuming that `venue` is name of the ForeignKey field linking room to venue.  If a venue can have many rooms,  but a room can only have one venue, then if you know the pk of a room, you don't need to separately know the pk of the venue it belongs to.  You can get that from the room object and django will do all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.

```
if room.pk == roompk:
```

roompk is a string i need to cast a int

```
  if room.pk == int(roompk):
```